# bootstrap modal for file upload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, modal-dialog

I have been using bootstrap modal through out my application which is developed in asp.net mvc. Now I am stuck while trying to upload file using bootstrap Model. With normal ajax, the controller did showed null in HttpPostedFileBase. I then used JQuery.Form.js, and switched from @using (Html.BeginHtml to @using (Ajax.BeginForm. With this the file shown in HttpPostedFileBase. But however, this time Callback is not working. Here is the javascript snippet that had been used

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).delegate("a[data-ajax-model]", "click", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindAjaxForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function bindAjaxForm(dialog) {    
    $('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ajaxForm').ajaxForm({
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert('test0');
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#replacetarget').html(data);
                Initialize_ThreeFixDT();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert('test');
                $('#myModalContent').html(xhr.responseText, xhr.status);
                bindAjaxForm(dialog);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with bootstrap modal doing full postback and the modal does not return after postback. So I used a `Hiddenfield` as a flag.

When a submit button is pressed for file upload I am giving value as `1` for `HiddenField`. And in document.ready of JQuery writing code to show popup modals if `HiddenField` value is `1`.

I am also making `HiddenField` value to `0` if `1`.